# ¿Como puedo devolver una variable de una funcion en python?

Tags: python, array, funciones, variables

Mi codigo es el sigiente:

```
import os
n=3;mayor=0;valores=[];
def Mayor(valores,mayor,i):
    if valores[i]>mayor:
        mayor=valores[i]
    return mayor

for i in range(n):
    print("Valores ingresados:",i+1,"/",n)
    print("Ingrese",n,"valores que desee..")
    x=int(input("Valor: "))
    valores.append(x)
    Mayor(valores,mayor,i)
    os.system("cls")
print("El valor mas alto ingresado es",mayor)
os.system("pause")
```

como es evidente, al imprimir "mayor" me arroja 0, el print necesito que esté en la función principal y no moverlo a la función "Mayor()"
¿Existe una forma de que la variable "mayor" retorne a la función principal? Sin usar la llamada:

```
mayor=Mayor(valores,i)
```

Comment: es tan simple como hacer `mayor=max(valores)`

Comment: Como dice @Bryro, solo debes de hacerle `append()` a las entradas de usuario y luego `max()` a la lista total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para empezar, no es necesario que hagas una función para saber el valor mas alto de una lista, python y muchos otros lenguajes de programación cuentan con muchas funciones integradas, entre esas funciones esta la función: max la cual devuelve el valor mas alto de una lista, ejemplo:

```
print(max([1, 5, 3]))
```

salida:

```
5
```

entonces tu programa quedaría así:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

```
n = 3
valores = []

for i in range(n):
    print("Valores ingresados: " + str(i + 1) + "/" + str(n))
    print("Ingrese " + str(n) + " valores que desee...")
    x=int(input("Valor: "))
    valores.append(x)
    
print("El valor mas alto ingresado es: " + str(max(valores)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Casi lo hicistes bien.

Estas usando una variable global (mayor), que se confunde con el argumento de la función. Por lo demás, es innecesario pasar "mayor" como parámetro si lo tienes definido como global.

Solución:

1. Elimina "mayor" de la lista de argumentos.
2. Estas usando los mismos nombres para variables globales ("valores") y argumentos de la función. Esto generar confusión y te traerá problemas sin fin a la hora de depurar tu programa. Renombra las variables para hacerlas diferentes.
3. Declara "global mayor" dentro de la función. De otro modo, "mayor" sólo sería una variable local, distinta al "mayor" que pones fuera.

   ```
   n=3
   mayor=0
   valores_in=[];

   def Mayor(valores,i):
       global mayor
       if valores[i]>mayor:
           mayor=valores[i]
       return mayor

   for i in range(n):
       print("Valores ingresados:",i+1,"/",n)
       print("Ingrese",n,"valores que desee..")
       x=int(input("Valor: "))
       valores_in.append(x)
       Mayor(valores_in,i)

   print("El valor mas alto ingresado es",mayor)
   ```

genera:

```
Valores ingresados: 1 / 3
Ingrese 3 valores que desee..
Valor: 3
Valores ingresados: 2 / 3
Ingrese 3 valores que desee..
Valor: 6
Valores ingresados: 3 / 3
Ingrese 3 valores que desee..
Valor: 3
El valor mas alto ingresado es 6
```

**Otras observaciones**

No tiene mucho sentido llamar a la función tres veces, pasando la lista "valores_in" y el indice "i". Podrías pasar la lista completa y resolver el tema de una vez, o mejor, usar la función "max"

```
n=3
valores_in=[]

for i in range(n):
    print("Valores ingresados:",i+1,"/",n)
    print("Ingrese",n,"valores que desee..")
    x=int(input("Valor: "))
    valores_in.append(x)

mayor = max(valores_in)
print("El valor mas alto ingresado es",mayor)
```

Comment: Muy Bien,¿Como podría hacerlas locales a las variables n=3
mayor=0
valores_in=[];?